# Why is vscode not running any of my codes?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS code is not running my code for some reason I've been trying to fix this problem for two weeks

When I say not run the code I don't mean that VS code is showing an error **no**, I mean that VS code isn't even running the code.

I tried (ctrl + alt + N) but nothing happened, I also tried other ways too and still nothing,
and I have just noticed that this problem also happens with every single code I have.

the terminal shows nothing as VS code doesn't even run the code, and I even uninstalled VS code and reinstalled it again and the problem is still present

Comment: Can you share the `launch.json` in your `.vscode` folder? Also, ctrl+alt+N shouldn't run any code. The shortcut for running/debugging code is fn+f5.

Comment: Also, what other ways have you tried to execute your code?